# Embeddable html5 audio player

Tags: php, html, embed

I am looking for a way to have an embeddable html5 player on a website. How possible is that? I have seen another website achieving that, with the technique of creating an additional page with only the html5 player and then iframe-ing it.
Example.
The page url;

```
http://www.hotnewhiphop.com/freddie-gibbs-pull-up-song.841426.html
```

The iframe with the html5 player-only page.

```
<iframe src="http://www.hotnewhiphop.com/freddie-gibbs-pull-up-embedsong.841426.html" style="width:442px;height:53px;border-width:0;" width="442" height="53"></iframe>
```

How is that done in php (maybe a brief explanation)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JWPLayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/).  It's somewhat of a defacto industry standard, and though it's primary focus is on video, it supports audio as well.  Covers HTML5 too.